# Print barcode out with pdfkit

Tags: node.js, pdfkit

I want to print jewellery barcode out in nodejs as in image.
[image]
My code is

```
  var doc = new PDFDocument({
   size: [200,100]
  });
  doc.font('Times-Roman')
      .fontSize(7)
      .text("1.49G",100,4);
  doc.font('./public/fonts/LibreBarcode39-Regular.ttf')
      .fontSize(18)
      .text('12345678',145,4,{align:"right"});
  doc.font('Times-Roman')
        .fontSize(7)
        .text("DC1",100,20)
        .text("120,000MMK",145,20,{align:"left"});
  doc.end();
  doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream("./public/upload/barcode/doc.pdf"));
```

And it works as

[image]

But I have two problems:

1. It change to portrait when I print barcode out.

[image]

2. And then, size: [200,100] is not my real idea. Barcode have many extra at bottom as picture(2). The size I want is [200,50]. When I change size from [200,100] into [200,50], many template appear. size [200,50] is enough to design the barcode I want. But it split as in picture(4).

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated!